# Pegar conteudo de uma Tag HTML com JS

Tags: javascript, html

Bom... minha duvida é como capturar o valor que fica entre:

`<ALGUMATAGHTML> O valor definido arqui</ALGUMATAGHTML>`

Sendo que o valor que quero capturar fica em:

`<span style="" id="streamurl">Aqui!!!</span>`

Tentei com JavaScript mas não deu certo. Código em JS:

```
var url = document.getElementById('streamurl').value;
alert(url);
```

Alguém aí sabe como pega isso em JS?

Comment: Não deu pra entender. O que é "Aqui"? Qual o elemento com id "streamurl"?

Comment: @Dvdsamm respondi e removi até a pergunta ser editada rs, o dedo coça pra responder.

Comment: Edite a pergunta explicando melhor a questão.

Comment: Acabei de reajustar a pergunta, o problema é que essa é minha primeira vez no stack e não sabia da restrição de HTMl, então acaba sumindo todo o codigo que colava no post... Malz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vai depender de que tipo de `tag` você quer.

> **value** - Essa propriedade retorna o valor inserido em campos de formulário, como *inputs* e *checkboxes*, etc..

```js
var url = document.getElementById('streamurl').value;
alert(url);
```

```html
<input type="text" size="60" id="streamurl" value="http://google.com" />
```

> **innertText** e **text** - Essas duas propriedades retornam o texto que está no interior de um container, como uma *div*, *span*, etc..

```js
var url = document.getElementById('streamurl').text;
alert(url);

var url = document.getElementById('streamurl').innerText;
alert(url);
```

```html
<a id="streamurl" href="#">pt.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

> **innertHTML** - Essa propriedade retorna não somente o texto que está no interior, mas também as *tags* que estivem também.

```js
var url = document.getElementById('streamurl').innerHTML;
alert(url);
```

```html
<a id="streamurl" href="#">Link 2 <i>Tag</i></a>
```

Comment: Bom... Por enquanto o código da primeira resposta serviu bem para o proposito, agora basta criar um para montar uma url usando essa informação e força o redirecionamento da pagina.

Comment: Para isso, cria uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Tô tentando criar usando o site "w3schools.com", se não conseguir usando as referencias de la, votarei para mais uma pergunta...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerHTML` em vez de `.value`:

```
var url = document.getElementById('streamurl').innerHTML;
alert(url);
```

```js
var url = document.getElementById('streamurl').innerHTML;
    alert(url);
```

```html
<span style="" id="streamurl">Aqui!!!</span>
```

Comment: Vlw cara... tem algum lugar para marcar como resposta certa?

Comment: Sim, abaixo da seta à esquerda de resposta.

Comment: Pronto vlw... Boa noite

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz Que bom que ajudou! Agora, eu recomendaria não usar a variável `url` porque pode dar conflito qualquer hora com alguma biblioteca ou plugin, sei lá... Eu também usava `url` nos meus códigos, até q um dia eles pararam de funcionar. Bastou eu mudar para `url_`que tudo voltou a funcionar, mas me deu um trabalhão ir atrás de alterar todos os `url` dos códigos em várias páginas. Eu costumo evitar usar variáveis com nomes comuns (`url` é um deles), por isso adicionei um sublinhado.

Comment: VLW pela dica, mas esse código em especial é para funcionar em um script do Tampermonkey, especifico para o site openload.co, com o objetivo de converter o player deles para um em HTMl5 que eu uso...

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz, blz! Se tá funcionando tá ótimo. Eu que parei de usar pq eu sempre usava nos meus Ajax e nunca deu problema, até que um certo dia o Ajax não funcionava e descobri que era essa variável `url`. Troquei por `url_` e funfou beleza e nunca mais deu problema :)

Comment: Trocando agora kkk - Melhor me acostumar a não utilizar...

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz rsrs boa! É melhor mesmo evitar. Tipo, por exemplo, dar nome de campo em banco de dados de "data": embora data seja uma palavra em português, é também uma palavra em inglês que é reservada por muitas linguagens de programação. Resultado: vai dar problema no código rs.

Comment: Compreendi... FLW