# Copiar texto dentro da <span> para clipboard

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Bom dia... Gostaria que ao clicar no link copiar, ele copiasse o texto dentro do span. Alguém pode me ajudar, fazendo o exemplo que funciona com elemento input, funcionar (seguindo o mesmo padrão, ou tornando-o melhor).

```
<span id="ip_publisher">TEXTO EXEMPLO</span>
<a href="#" role="button" onClick="copyIpPublisher()" style="padding: .12rem .2rem !important; font-size: .56em !important;">Copiar</a>

<script>
  function copyIpPublisher(){
  var tl_sel = document.getElementById("ip_publisher");
  tl_sel.select();

  document.execCommand('copy');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp dá uma olhada

Comment: o exemplos são para copiar a partir de input, preciso a partir do span, p, div etc. mas obrigado.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25303/pegar-conte%C3%BAdo-de-dentro-de-uma-div-e-colocar-no-value-do-input um exemplo com jQuery

Comment: outro exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242202/54880 javascript puro

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Pegar conteudo de uma Tag HTML com JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242199/pegar-conteudo-de-uma-tag-html-com-js)

Comment: em parte. o exemplo mostra no alerta, mas não copia.

Comment: Obrigado novic e Ricardo Pontual, ajudou. Mas acabei achando aqui https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/htmlcss/how-to-copy-text-from-html-element-to-clipboard.html

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, amigo.
Tenta utilizar: navigator.clipboard.writeText("texto_para_ser_copiado");

```js
function copyIpPublisher(){
    let tl_sel = document.getElementById('ip_publisher').innerHTML;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(tl_sel);
    console.log('Copiado '+ tl_sel + ' para a Área de Trânsferência...');
  }
```

```html
<span id="ip_publisher">TEXTO EXEMPLO</span>
<a href="#" role="button" onClick="copyIpPublisher()" style="padding: .12rem .2rem !important; font-size: .56em !important;">Copiar</a>
```

Obs.: Se você executar nesta página, pode não funcionar. Tenta na sua aplicação.